# Sender receiver availability in JMS pub/sub domain

Tags: jms

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdr.html) it states "the sender and the receiver do not have to be available at the same time in order to communicate.". And [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdx.html) it states that in pub/sub domain "A client that subscribes to a topic can consume only messages published after the client has created a subscription, and *the subscriber must continue to be active in order for it to consume messages*.". To me the italicized statement seems to contradict the first statement("the sender and the receiver do not have to be available at the same time").

If the subscriber must continue to be active to consume messages, it means the sender and the receiver *must* be available at the same time at least in the pub/sub domain. If they must be available, the pub/sub domain is only as good as RMI. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...the sender and the receiver do not have to be available at the same time in order to communicate.

As far as I can tell this is a general statement about *messaging* and not a nuanced explanation of the semantics the JMS API provides. Notice it is under the "What Is Messaging?" heading before specific discussion of the JMS API begins.

For what it's worth, the JMS API *does provide these semantics if you're using the **point-to-point** style of messaging* (also discussed in the tutorial). It also provides a variation of these semantics using the pub-sub style of messaging, but I'll get to that later.

> A client that subscribes to a topic can consume only messages published after the client has created a subscription, and the subscriber must continue to be active in order for it to consume messages.

If you read the next sentence after that you'll find some important additional details:

> The JMS API relaxes this timing dependency to some extent by allowing subscribers to create **durable subscriptions**, which receive messages sent while the subscribers are not active.

So, as I mentioned previously, you can get a variation of the inactive sender/receiver semantics using the pub-sub style of messaging via durable subscriptions.

Keep in mind that the document you're referencing is just a tutorial. It's not the JMS specification. I doubt the wording of the tutorial was subjected to the same scrutiny as the specification so you are more likely to find ambiguous statements.